# Can I set a pytorch dataloader with multiple workers to load as fifo and not take turns?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have created a pytorch (iterable)dataset which will load my data. However some samples can take quite some time to load while other samples are faster to load. I want my dataloader to return a batch as soon as it managed to load all samples. How can I achieve this?

I have created an example to explain in more detail what I want to achieve.

```py
import torch
import math
import time

class MyIterableDataset(torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        super(MyIterableDataset).__init__()
        assert end > start, "this example code only works with end >= start"
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def give_data(self, start, end):
        for i in range(start, end):
            if i > 10:
                time.sleep(2)
            yield i

    def __iter__(self):
        worker_info = torch.utils.data.get_worker_info()
        if worker_info is None:  # single-process data loading, return the full iterator
            iter_start = self.start
            iter_end = self.end
        else:  # in a worker process
            # split workload
            per_worker = int(math.ceil((self.end - self.start) / float(worker_info.num_workers)))
            worker_id = worker_info.id
            iter_start = self.start + worker_id * per_worker
            iter_end = min(iter_start + per_worker, self.end)
        return self.give_data(iter_start, iter_end)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ds = MyIterableDataset(start=0, end=20)

    # Mult-process loading with two worker processes
    for item in (torch.utils.data.DataLoader(ds, num_workers=2, batch_size=2)):
        print(item)
```

The result of this script will be

```py
tensor([0, 1]) # Loaded fast
tensor([10, 11])  # Loaded slowly
tensor([2, 3])  # Loaded fast
tensor([12, 13])  # Loaded slowly
tensor([4, 5])  # Loaded fast
tensor([14, 15])  # Loaded slowly
tensor([6, 7])  # Loaded fast
tensor([16, 17])  # Loaded slowly
tensor([8, 9])  # Loaded fast
tensor([18, 19])  # Loaded slowly
```

while what I want to achieve is that it returns something like this. The slowly loaded data took longer but it manage to load several faster-batches in the meantime.

```py
tensor([0, 1]) # Loaded fast
tensor([2, 3])  # Loaded fast
tensor([4, 5])  # Loaded fast
tensor([6, 7])  # Loaded fast
tensor([10, 11])  # Loaded slowly
tensor([8, 9])  # Loaded fast
tensor([12, 13])  # Loaded slowly
tensor([14, 15])  # Loaded slowly
tensor([16, 17])  # Loaded slowly
tensor([18, 19])  # Loaded slowly
```

Comment: I would think the dataloader _should_ load first-available data from any worker (it uses a Queue that all workers write to). This sounds like a bug to me. might be worth filing a github issue.

Comment: I've opened an issue that can be found here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/105203